# Is there any way to establish uniform bounds on an almost surely converging sequence?

Tags: probability, analysis

I have a quantity $X_n$ converging to $X$ almost surely and $X$ is bounded. Is there any way to show that $\sup_n X_n$ is bounded somehow?

In more detail, I want to show that there is some bound on $W(P_n,Q)$, the Wasserstein between $P_n$ and $Q$. I know $W(P_n,Q)$ converges to $W(P,Q)$ almost surely so I wasn't sure if that could be used to control $W(P_n,Q)$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $X_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ converges as. to $0$. But $sup_nX_n(\omega)=[\frac 1 {\omega}]-1$ which is not bounded.

Comment: Okay, so is there any way I can control $W(P_n,Q)$ then? I need to control this somehow.

Comment: Can I send you a private message with more details?